# Can I use app.py instead of __init__.py for my Flask application factory?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I have a Flask application roughly structured as:

```
my_app/
   __init__.py  # Contains create_app()
   utils/
       __init__.py  # Useful functions

other_stuff.py
```

Everything works, but when I `import my_app.utils` in `other_stuff.py`, it also executes some Flask-specific code in `__init__.py`, which is somewhat undesirable for my use case.

So, I renamed `__init__.py` to `app.py` and the env variable `FLASK_APP=my_app` to `FLASK_APP=my_app.app` .

```
my_app/
   app.py  # Contains create_app()
   utils/
       __init__.py  # Useful functions

other_stuff.py
```

Everything seems to work great. However, this structure is not mentioned in the Flask documentation or any tutorial.

Are there any reasons **not** to go with this method?

(Also, should `create_app()` use `app = Flask('my_app')` or `app = Flask('my_app.app')`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no reason why you couldn't do that.

Something you might consider, though, if your app consists of bits that are flask-dependent and non-flask-dependent is to put the flask bits in a different package altogether:

```
my_app/
  __init__.py
  some_other_web_stuff.py
my_tools/
  __init__.py
```

or maybe

```
my_app/
  web/
    __init__.py
    some_other_web_stuff.py
  utils/
    __init__.py
```

Comment: Thanks! The alternate structure is a good idea, but the current one seems semantically cleaner (for my situation). Btw, I had a follow-up question: should `create_app()` use `app = Flask('my_app')` or `app = Flask('my_app.app')`?

Comment: Looks like [it should be](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask) `app = Flask('my_app')`.